# How do I map an IS-A relationship into a database?

Tags: database-design

Consider the following:

```
entity User
{
    autoincrement uid;
    string(20) name;
    int privilegeLevel;
}

entity DirectLoginUser
{
    inherits User;
    string(20) username;
    string(16) passwordHash;
}

entity OpenIdUser
{
    inherits User;
    //Whatever attributes OpenID needs... I don't know; this is hypothetical
}
```

The different kinds of users (Direct Login users, and OpenID users) display an IS-A relationship; namely, that both types of users are users. Now, there are several ways this can be represented in an RDBMS:

**Way One**

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    uid INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    privlegeLevel INTEGER NOT NULL,
    type ENUM("DirectLogin", "OpenID") NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    passwordHash VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    //OpenID Attributes
    PRIMARY_KEY(uid)
)
```

**Way Two**

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    uid INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    privilegeLevel INTEGER NOT NULL,
    type ENUM("DirectLogin", "OpenID") NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY_KEY(uid)
)

CREATE TABLE DirectLogins
(
    uid INTEGER NOT_NULL,
    username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    passwordHash VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY_KEY(uid),
    FORIGEN_KEY (uid) REFERENCES Users.uid
)

CREATE TABLE OpenIDLogins
(
    uid INTEGER NOT_NULL,
    // ...
    PRIMARY_KEY(uid),
    FORIGEN_KEY (uid) REFERENCES Users.uid
)
```

**Way Three**

```
CREATE TABLE DirectLoginUsers
(
    uid INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    privlegeLevel INTEGER NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    passwordHash VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY_KEY(uid)
)

CREATE TABLE OpenIDUsers
(
    uid INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    privlegeLevel INTEGER NOT NULL,
    //OpenID Attributes
    PRIMARY_KEY(uid)
)
```

I'm almost certain the third way is the wrong way, because it's not possible to do a simple join against users elsewhere in the database.

My real world example is not a users with different logins example though; I'm interested in how to model this relationship in the general case.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the approach suggested in the comments by Joel Brown. It should work for you. If you're looking for more suggestions, I would re-tag your question to indicate you are looking for a MySQL-specific answer.

Comment: Note it really depends upon how the relations are used in the rest of the database. Relationships involving the child entities require foreign keys to just those tables, and prohibit mapping to a single unifying table without some hackiness.

Comment: In object-relational databases like PostgreSQL, there's actually a fourth way: you can declare a table INHERITS from another table. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-inheritance.html

Answer (score 17):

**Way two is the correct way.**

Your base class gets a table, and then child classes get their own tables with just the additional fields they introduce, plus foreign key references to the base table.

As [Joel](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3106/joel-brown) suggested in his comments on this answer, you can guarantee that a user will have either a direct login or an OpenID login, but not both (and also possibly neither) by adding a type column to each sub-type table that keys back to the root table. The type column in each sub-type table is restricted to have a single value representing the type of that table. Because this column is foreign keyed to the root table, only one sub-type row can link to the same root row at a time.

For example, the MySQL DDL would look something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
      uid               INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL
    , type              ENUM("DirectLogin", "OpenID") NOT NULL
    // ...

    , PRIMARY_KEY(uid)
);

CREATE TABLE DirectLogins
(
      uid               INTEGER NOT_NULL
    , type              ENUM("DirectLogin") NOT NULL
    // ...

    , PRIMARY_KEY(uid)
    , FORIGEN_KEY (uid, type) REFERENCES Users (uid, type)
);

CREATE TABLE OpenIDLogins
(
      uid               INTEGER NOT_NULL
    , type              ENUM("OpenID") NOT NULL
    // ...

    PRIMARY_KEY(uid),
    FORIGEN_KEY (uid, type) REFERENCES Users (uid, type)
);
```

(On other platforms you would use a `CHECK` constraint instead of `ENUM`.) MySQL [supports](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) composite foreign keys so this should work for you.

Way one is valid, though you are wasting space in those `NULL`-able columns because their use depends on the type of user.  The advantage is that if you choose to expand what kinds of user types to store and those types don't require additional columns, you can just expand the domain of your `ENUM` and use the same table.

Way three forces any queries that reference users to check against both tables. This also prevents you from referencing a single users table via foreign key.

Comment: How do I deal with the fact that using way 2, there's no way to enforce that there is exactly one corresponding row in the two other tables?

Comment: @Billy - Good objection. If your users can only have one or the other, you can enforce this via your proc layer or triggers. I wonder if there is a DDL-level way to enforce this constraint. (Alas, indexed views [do not allow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921(v=sql.100).aspx) `UNION`, or I would have suggested an indexed view with a unique index against the `UNION ALL` of `uid` from the two tables.)

Comment: Of course that assumes that your RDBMS supported indexed views in the first place.

Comment: @Billy - That's true. SQL Server and Oracle, for example, do support indexed views, while MySQL doesn't. The database-agnostic answer would be to enforce a cross-table constraint like this using triggers or proc logic.

Comment: A handy way to implemet this kind of cross-table constraint would be to include a partitioning attribute in the super-type table.  Then each sub-type can check to ensure that it relates only to super-types that have the appropriate partitioning attribute value.  This saves having to do a collision test by looking at one or more other sub-type tables.

Comment: @Joel - So, for example, we add a `type` column to each sub-type table that is restricted via `CHECK` constraint to have exactly one value (that table's type). Then, we make the sub-table foreign keys to the super-table into composite ones on both `uid` and `type`. That's ingenious.

Comment: @Nick: Sadly, not all RDBMSs support CHECK constraints either. :(

Comment: @Billy - What RDBMS are you using? Perhaps it is not appropriate for your needs. :) Though not ideal, you can use `INSERT`/`UPDATE` triggers if `CHECK` constraints are not available.

Comment: @Nick: Unfortunately I'm stuck using MySQL. I'm not happy about it. PostgreSQL would be nice... though it doesn't support that kind of CHECK constraint either (limited to looking at the current table row)

Comment: @Billy - See my updated answer. `CHECK` constraints are not required.

Comment: @BillyONeal - Does my update address all your concerns? I'm curious to know how you ended up implementing this.

Comment: @Nick: I ended up using the separate tables with the addons method (as you suggested), but I didn't end up using the FK constraint to ensure that happens.

Answer (score 5):

They would be named

1. [Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html)
2. [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html)
3. [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html).

and all have their legitimate uses and are supported by some libraries. You have to find out which fits best.

Having multiple tables would make take the data management more to your application code but would reduce the amount of unused space.

Comment: There is an additional technique called "Shared Primary Key".   In this technique, the subclass tables do not have an independently assigned primary key id.  Instead, the PK of the subclass tables is the FK that references the superclass table.  This provides several benefits, mainly that it enforces the one-to-one nature of IS-A relationships.  This technique is an add on to Class Table Inheritance.