# Does the order of keys in compound Primary key make any difference?

Tags: mysql, primary-key

Package

```
Package
-------
PackageID
PackageName
CityID
PRIMARY KEY (PackageID)
UNIQUE KEY (PackageName)
FOREIGN KEY (CityID)
  REFERENCES City (CityID)
```

**Package versions**:

```
PackageVersion
--------------
PackageID
VersionNumber
PackageType
PRIMARY KEY (PackageID, VersionNumber)
UNIQUE KEY (PackageID, VersionNumber, PackageType)
FOREIGN KEY (PackageID)
  REFERENCES Package (PackageID)
and subtypes (of versions):

LandPackageVersion
------------------
PackageID
VersionNumber
PackageType  DEFAULT 'L'
PRIMARY KEY (PackageID, VersionNumber, PackageType)
FOREIGN KEY (PackageID, VersionNumber, PackageType)
  REFERENCES PackageVersion (PackageID, VersionNumber, PackageType)

FlightPackageVersion
------------------
PackageID
VersionNumber
PackageType  DEFAULT 'F'
OriginID
PRIMARY KEY (PackageID, VersionNumber, PackageType)
FOREIGN KEY (PackageID, VersionNumber, PackageType)
  REFERENCES PackageVersion (PackageID, VersionNumber, PackageType)
FOREIGN KEY (OriginID)
  REFERENCES City (CityID)
```

---

When I define **PackageVersion** (read `PackageVariant`) table, I mark VersionNumber (aka `idPackageVariant`) as Auto Increment and a part of Primary Key in the order defined above:

> PRIMARY KEY (`idHolidayPackage`, `idPackageVariant`)

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wah_schema`.`HolidayPackageVariant` (
  `idHolidayPackage` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `idPackageVariant` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `packageType` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

  **PRIMARY KEY (`idHolidayPackage`, `idPackageVariant`) ,**

  UNIQUE INDEX `idHolidayPackage_UNIQUE` (`idHolidayPackage` ASC, `idPackageVariant` ASC, `packageType` ASC) ,

  INDEX `fk_HolidayPackageVariant_HolidayPackage` (`idHolidayPackage` ASC) ,

  CONSTRAINT `fk_HolidayPackageVariant_HolidayPackage`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idHolidayPackage` )
    REFERENCES `wah_schema`.`HolidayPackage` (`idHolidayPackage` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

However, due to this [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60104) in mySql, I need to have `AutoIncrement Key` as the first part of the Primary Key in a compound key.

So, does the order of keys in compound Primary key make any difference ?

Just for reference, the above design comes from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14665/1008).

Comment: You can't have an auto-incremented column as part of a compound Primary Key in InnoDB. Unfortunately. The VersionNumbers have to be supplied by the application (or a trigger).

Comment: You can have `VersionNumber` as auto_increment and PK and `(PackageID, VersionNumber)` as Unique. Or vice-versa. But that's not what VersionNumber is supposed to be, isn't it?

Comment: @ypercube Shouldn't the combination of PackageId and `VersionNumber` be unique to identify a unique variant for a given package ? If I make VersionNumber auto_increment, the combination becomes unique. Also, the unique combination helps in identifying a unique variant for a given package also.

Comment: It's a `One`:`Many` relationship between `Package`:`PackageVariant`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of keys can make a difference depending on your access pattern.

Example...

You want to find `MAX(idPackageVariant)` for a single`idHolidayPackage`

With idHolidayPackage as the second column, then the index will be scanned. With idHolidayPackage as the first, it can be seeked which is more efficient.

This is a specifiy MySQL problem of course. IIRCl you'll need to do this. InnoDB uses the first unique key as the *clustered* index which may or may not be the primary key. However, this may not be the case

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wah_schema`.`HolidayPackageVariant` (
  `idHolidayPackage` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `idPackageVariant` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `packageType` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

  UNIQUE INDEX `idHolidayPackage_UNIQUE` (`idHolidayPackage` ASC, `idPackageVariant` ASC, `packageType` ASC) ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`idHolidayPackage`, `idPackageVariant`) ,

  -- not needed INDEX `fk_HolidayPackageVariant_HolidayPackage` (`idHolidayPackage` ASC) ,

  CONSTRAINT `fk_HolidayPackageVariant_HolidayPackage`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idHolidayPackage` )
    REFERENCES `wah_schema`.`HolidayPackage` (`idHolidayPackage` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Alternatively, you can just have `idPackageVariant` as the primary and clustered key for efficiency.

Comment: I will mostly do a lookup on PackageVariant based on idHolidayPackage, so it makes sense for keeping idHolidayPackage as the first part in the the compound key.

Comment: I don't understand what a clustered index is, so I didn't understand what you wrote about clustered index. However, as for the snippet posted by you, it won't work in MySQL due to the bug I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Also, if I just have idPackageVariant as the primary key, then as you suggested, the db would then do a scan for idHolidayPackage everytime I access a variant using idHolidayPackage ?

Comment: what do you think ?